# Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token getting expire after 2 Hour

Tags: c#, windows-phone, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have implemented google Oauth 2.0 authorization in C# Project,my access-token expires within 2 hours.
How can i get the token which can work for longer.

Answer (score 3):

You can not set the lifespan of access token. OAuth 2.0 has refresh token which is typically long-lasting credential used to request additional access tokens.

So in Google OAuth 2.0, you can use [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) to obtain new access tokens at any time.

Comment: Thanks...But is there any time limit for refresh token?

Comment: The refresh token will not expire until the user revokes access to your application.